# TestNG: How to validate test results in a common function

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have a bunch of tests in my test suite.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
  // test 1
  assert...
}

@Test
public void test2() {
  // test 2
  assert...
}
```

I have another method called 'verify()' that does some extra asserts after the tests are completed.

```
void verify() {
  // more asserts that are common to test1() and test2()
}
```

To make use of these asserts in verify(), the straightforward way I can think of is to add verify() at the end of each test. But is there a more elegant or simpler way that this?

I looked at TestNG's @AfterMethod (and @AfterTest). If I add @AfterMethod to verify(), the asserts in verify() are executed. But if the asserts passes, they do not show up in the test report. If the assert fails, those failures are marked as configuration failures and not test failures.

How can I ensure that verify() is always called after each test is run and still report the results of asserts within the verify() as part of the test results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can basically have your test class implement the interface `org.testng.IHookable`.

When TestNG sees that a class implements this interface, then TestNG doesn't call your `@Test` methods directly, but instead it calls the `run()` method from the `IHookable` implementation from wherein you are expected to trigger the test method invocation by invoking the callback on the `org.testng.IHookCallBack` which is passed to you.

Here's a sample that shows this in action:

```
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class MyTestClass implements IHookable {
    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        commonTestCode();
    }

    public void commonTestCode() {
        System.err.println("commonTestCode() executed.");

    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        System.err.println("testMethod1() executed.");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        System.err.println("testMethod2() executed.");
    }
}
```

Here's the output of the execution:

```
testMethod1() executed.
commonTestCode() executed.
testMethod2() executed.
commonTestCode() executed.

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```